# Final keyword in for statement

Tags: java

I was reading some code found on the web and fell on these lines (java):

```
private List<String> values;

[...]

for (final String str : values) {
   length += context.strlen(str);
}
```

What is the advantage of declaring a variable final in a for loop ? I thought the variable specified in the for loop was already read-only (e.g. can't assign something to 'str' in the above example).

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *What is the advantage of declaring a variable final in a for loop ?*

Not much in a small piece of code, but, if it would help to avoid changing the reference while looping.

For instance:

```
for( String s : values ) {
     computeSomething( s );
      ... a dozen of lines here... 
     s = s.trim();// or worst s = getOtherString();
     ... another dozen of line 
     otherComputation( s );
 }
```

If you don't use final, the last line `anotherComputation` can potentially use a different value than the one was defined in the iteration and subtle bugs may be introduced, while reading other code the maintainer will try to figure out how come that method is failing with the correct values.

For a 5 - 15 lines long for  this is easy to spot, but for larger segments of code, believe me, is much harder.

Using `final` will prevent value change at compile time.

```
... 
for( final String s : values ) {
  s = new StringBuilder( s ).reverse().toString();
}
```

This code fails at compile time `variable s might already have been assigned`

Another advantage could be to allow the variable to be used  inside an anonymous inner class:

```
for( final String s : value ) {
    doSomething( new InnerClass() {
       void something() {
             s.length();// accesing s from within the inner class 
       }
    });
 }
```

Comment: Don't you think that if a large segment of code is difficult to comprehend, it should be broken down into sub-routines or something like that, instead of injection of itty-bitty little constraints?  Thanks for the inner class example, though, that's interesting.

Comment: @Nikita: One word: **definitely** , if possible the code in a for loop shouldn't exceed 10 lines long, a method should contain only one for loop, and nesting loops should be avoided as much as possible. That's what * I * would like, but, sometimes you have to work with other people and sometimes you have to maintain their code, and sometimes a bug that is holding production was produced by  something as subtle as this :'(

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a loop variable as final is a purely stylistic thing:

- You protect yourself from accidentally adding a statement to the loop body that changes the loop variable.
- You make it clear to someone else reading the code that the loop variable won't change in the loop body.

I personally don't think this is a big thing.  But that's because I'd never write code that does this ... without adding a big bold comment to explain what was going on, and why I'd decided to do it that way.  (But I can see the point if you are in environment where such abominations are commonplace ...)

> I thought the variable specified in the for loop was already read-only (e.g. can't assign something to 'str' in the above example).

Nope.  A for loop variable (provided it is not declared as `final`) **can** be modified in the body of the loop.

If you want to read the nitty-gritty details, the for loop is described in the [JLS section 14.14](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14).  It does not explicitly mention loop variables declared as `final`.  But the general picture is that the only difference between a loop variable defined declared in the `for` statement and any other variable is the scoping.

Answer (score 1):

*I thought the variable specified in the for loop was already read-only*
It's not read-only, try it.

Some people like declaring local variables 'final', not sure why. And looks like this is such case.

In any case, don't consider arbitrary code sample you found on the web to be style model.

Comment: Nikita, this ( answer )  is a very good candidate for a "comment" instead of an answer.

Comment: @Nikyta "Some people like declaring local variables 'final'"... Its a way of making emphasys on the fact that something will not change for the rest of its lifetime.....In addition to having a representative name, a variable can be 'more readable' this way.

Comment: Guys, I understand that this is all for the sake of immutability, I just see little point in such micromanagement.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not read only. Its a temporary variable that has the scope of the loop.

By adding the `final` keyword, you are making it read only.

```
$ cat Finals.java
import java.util.List;


public class Finals {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        int ints[] = {1,2,3,4};

        for (Integer i:ints){
            i +=20;
            System.out.println(i);
        }    
    }    
}
$ javac Finals.java -cp .
$ java Finals
21
22
23
24
$
```

Answer (score 0):

It may sometimes be helpful to declare it as final in the case that this variable is used by creating an annonymous class.

For example:

```
    String[] names = {"my name"};
    for(final String name: names){
        new Object(){
            String objName = name;
        };
    }
```